# How to prevent Bootstrap-Slider of load before render correctly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-slider

I'm making a websurvey where I have to load several bootstrap-sliders for each individual page, submit and then move to the next where I have to load several bootstrap-sliders again.
The problem is that whenever the page is loading (right after pressing submit), it loads each individual bootstrap-slider (taking about more pixels space than it'll need) before snapping into the way it's supposed to render.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to load my page correctly? (i.e. rendering it only when it's "ready"?)

You can check a copy of my code at https://jsfiddle.net/MRT77/crmhqbaz/5/.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.1/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.4/nouislider.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.3.1/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uhut8PejFZO8994oEgm/ZfAv0mW1/b83nczZzSwElbeILxwkN491YQXsCFTE6+nx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container my-container">
      <form action="/submit-testSlim" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row my-row my-row-slider">
          <div class="col-5 text-right my-col">
            <label class="control-label" for="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" > </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 my-col">
            <input class="slider form-control" id="0" name="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-provide="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row my-row my-row-slider">
          <div class="col-5 text-right my-col">
            <label class="control-label" for="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" > </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 my-col">
            <input class="slider form-control" id="1" name="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-provide="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row my-row my-row-slider">
          <div class="col-5 text-right my-col">
            <label class="control-label" for="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" > </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 my-col">
            <input class="slider form-control" id="2" name="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-provide="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row my-row my-row-slider">
          <div class="col-5 text-right my-col">
            <label class="control-label" for="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" > </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 my-col">
            <input class="slider form-control" id="3" name="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-provide="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row my-row my-row-slider">
          <div class="col-5 text-right my-col">
            <label class="control-label" for="4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" > </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 my-col">
            <input class="slider form-control" id="4" name="4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-provide="slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.1/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.4/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css `display: none;` to your input selector, it will be load before javascript.

```
input.slider {
  display: none;
}
```

ex => https://jsfiddle.net/a0wsg7mo/

Comment: This solves the main issue, but it maintains a "slow" (and not smooth) rendering. Any other ideas to improve this?

Comment: JS need to create elements after DOM ready, let CSS prepare elements. Or add a display: none; on container and fade after slider loaded